# Average each of the column table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I have this script that made me stuck for two days.My aim is to get
>   the average of the column.My problem is in accessing the consecutive
>   rows and put the average in the last row in each column.

**-HTML-**

```
<table class="table" id="preview">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="6">
                                            <h3>School Name : 
                                                <select name="school_id" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="">Select School</option>
                                                    @foreach($location_name as $schools)
                                                    <optgroup label="{!! $schools->location_name !!}">
                                                        @foreach($schools['schoollocation'] as $scho)
                                                        <option value="{!! $scho->school_id !!}"@if($update_card->school_id == $scho->school_id)selected="selected" @endif>{!! $scho->school_name !!}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </h3>
                                        </th>
                                        <th colspan="3">
                                            <h3>Grade Level : 
                                                {!! Form::select('scholar_grade_level', [
                                                ''=>'Choose a Year Level',
                                                '7' => 'Grade-7',
                                                '8' => 'Grade-8',
                                                '9' => 'Grade-9',
                                                '10' => 'Grade-10'
                                                ],$update_card->scholar_grade_level,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                                            </h3>
                                        </th>
                                        <th colspan="3">
                                            <h3>School Year : 
                                                <select class="form-control" name="scholar_school_year">
                                                    <?php 
                                                    $null = 'null';
                                                    $choose = 'Choose A Year';
                                                    $Present = 'Present';
                                                    echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
                                                    if ($update_card->scholar_school_year ==  'Present' ) {
                                                        echo '<option value="Present" selected="selected">' .$Present.'</option>';
                                                    }else{
                                                        echo '<option value="Present">' .$Present.'</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-30; $i--){

                                                        $x = $i +1;
                                                        $y = $i;
                                                        $pass = $y.'-'.$x;
                                                        if ($update_card->scholar_school_year ==  $pass ) {
                                                            echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.' selected="selected">'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                                                        }else{
                                                            echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>                                           
                                            </h3>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="12"><h4>SCHOLASTIC ACHIEVEMENT</h4></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">Subjects</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">First Grading</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">Second Grading</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">Third Grading</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">Fourth Grading</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>   
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($update_card['AllGrade'] as $subject)
                                    {!! Form::hidden('grade_id[]',$subject['grade_id']) !!} 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">{!! $subject->subject !!}</td> 
                                        <td colspan="2" class="s"><input type="text" name="term_1[]" value="{!! $subject->term_1 !!}" class="form-control number-only" id="s1"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2" class="s"><input type="text" name="term_2[]" value="{!! $subject->term_2 !!}" class="form-control number-only" id="s2"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2" class="s"><input type="text" name="term_3[]" value="{!! $subject->term_3 !!}" class="form-control number-only" id="s3"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2" class="s"><input type="text" name="term_4[]" value="{!! $subject->term_4 !!}" class="form-control number-only" id="s4"></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">Average:</th>
                                        <td colspan="2" class="s"><input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" id="ss"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2" class="s"><input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" id="ss"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2" class="s"><input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" id="ss"></td>
                                        <td colspan="2" class="s"><input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" id="ss"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">Upload Card(Proof Grade) :</th>
                                        @foreach($update_card['CardProof'] as $subject1)
                                        {!! Form::hidden('card_proof_id',$subject1->card_proof_id) !!} 
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            {!! Form::file('card_proof_1') !!}
                                        </th> 
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            {!! Form::file('card_proof_2') !!}
                                        </th> 
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            {!! Form::file('card_proof_3') !!}
                                        </th> 
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            {!! Form::file('card_proof_4') !!}
                                        </th> 
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
```

**-Javascript-**

> This is what I have now...

```
var total = 0;
$('table#preview td.s').each(function()
{
    var input1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;  
    var input2 = document.getElementById("s2").value; 
    var input3 = document.getElementById("s3").value; 
    var input4 = document.getElementById("s4").value; 

    var score = parseInt($(this).text());
    alert(input1);


    if (!isNaN(score))
    {
        total += score;
    }
});

alert('The total is: ' + total);
```

**Desired output**

```
Subject | Term1 | Term2 | Term3 | Term4  
   Math      81      87      81      80    
Science      89      83      81      80
Average |    85 |    85 |    81 |    80
```

Comment: can you post the final html? You can get it by using `view page source` on your browser and just copying and pasting what comes out. Will be easier to test with an example

Comment: id should be unique

Comment: The solution below looks good but i cant get the value from input because the parsing of the script below is in td.It should be in the input.Any idea Sir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   <table>
  <thead>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Term1</th>
        <th>Term2</th>
        <th>Term3</th>
        <th>Term4</th>  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td><input type="text" value="Math"></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="81"></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="87"></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="81"></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="80"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><input type="text" value="SCEINCE"></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="89"></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="83"></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="81"></td>
       <td><input type="text" value="80"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="average">
       <td>Aerage</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>



 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#average td").each(function(k,v){
       debugger;
          if(k>0){
          $sum=0;
          $row = $(this).closest("table").find("tr");    
          $($row).each(function(key,val){
            if(key>0 && key<$row.length-1){
              $sum+=parseInt($($(this).find("input")[k]).val());      
            }
          })

          $(this).text($sum/($row.length-2));
          }

     })

    });
```

[check the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0nbmftx0/7/)

Comment: My td have input.It wont detect the value. <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="term_1[]" value="{!! $subject->term_1 !!}" class="form-control number-only"></td>.The value inside td is not  detected sir.

Comment: You can modify the code fetching td to fetch input instead, I have updated the fiddle and also the code :)

Comment: This answer is good..I just did a little bit  of accessing the input within the td.Thank you so much Sir to your kindness and sharing your true talent.